# Is there a way to maximize Youtube/flash videos to the size of window?

Tags: windows-7, firefox-extensions, flash-player

I have a single monitor on my home computer. Often when I'm using it, I'll put a video on the left half and whatever I'm working on on the right using W7's snap. I'd like the video to be the width of the left window, but my options are typically restricted to either the default size player (which leaves a lot of white space) or full screen. Sometimes I'll get lucky, such as with Youtube, where they'll offer a larger player, but this isn't ideal. Is there a way that I can get Flash or HTML5 videos to fill the the window it's contained in as opposed to the other options? I'm okay with letterboxing.

I'm currently using Firefox 27.

Thanks!

Comment: It's up to the player, and if its on a web page (like YouTube) you've got little control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option is to use browser's page zoom to control player's size. You can zoom in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and zoom out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

Another solution is to install [YouTube Center extension](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter). It offers a lot of features, including resizing the player to fit window's width.